# Images in different density in android

Tags: android

I create raw folder in my project and give reference of images from this folder in project.
So in case of different density will android make it's changes according to screen size.
or i have to put all images in drawable folder.
if yes then please let me know it's resolution and density ratio.

Comment: Better you go through this Article: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

Put images in different drawable folder itself rather than to give reference through raw folder. **You can create drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi**
These folders are for different resolutions and android select out of these folders according to screen size/resolution of device.

Answer (score 2):

Android already provide three drawable folder to store images for different density, this are
darwable-hdpi, darwable-mdpi, darwable-ldpi. you simply need to put images of different density into this folder with the same name. So that when the app run it automatically read images from this folder depending upon the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be helpful.

```
Density *mdpi   Resolution   Device                 iOS Equivalent      

ldpi     0.75   320 x 240    Galaxy Y                     0.75x
mdpi     1      480 x 320    Galaxy Ace                   1x
hdpi     1.5    480 x 854    Android One                  1.5x
xhdpi    2      768 x 1280   Nexus 4                      2x
xxhdpi   3      1080 x 1920  Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy S5   3x
xxxhdpi  4      1440 x 2560  Samsung Galaxy S6, S7        4x
```